# How to get text from div with a data-bind?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

```
<div class="col-num-two" data-bind="CurrentJob.addr">I need this text</div>
```

The data is AJAX'd in and I need to change the text inside.  I'm just using a 1 second timeout, but how do I select that div since there is no 'id' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the timeout fires use code like this:

```
var currentJobAddr  = document.querySelector ("div[data-bind='CurrentJob.addr']");
if (currentJobAddr)
    currentJobAddr  = currentJobAddr.textContent;
else
    alert ('Current job addr not found.')
```

[**See the code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vwsXY/)

Comment: Thanks Brock.  textContent is getting a null value, but I'll do some checking to see if the problem is elsewhere.  I think this should work

Comment: Hmm, still getting a null value no matter how long I wait.  The object is created fine, but textContent is null

Comment: Then the actual page does not match the question HTML. The code works, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/vwsXY/). ... Post a link to the target page.  Does the alert, from my answer fire?  Include the exact script you are testing.  Use http://pastebin.com/, if necessary.

Comment: The alert fires.  I believe the AJAX'd info isn't coming across on this particular page.  I should be able to take care of it from there, thanks for the help.  Btw Brock, did you grow up in Syracuse UT?  I knew a Brock Adams.

Comment: No, I probably drove by it, 20 or so times, on I-15; but I've never lived in Utah.